# Como saber qual formato de DATETIME utilizado em determinada coluna do SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Eu tenho uma tabela no SQL Server e um dos campos foi criado como `DATETIME`.

Como eu posso saber, via *query* ou SQL Server Studio, qual é o formato *default* utilizado deste `DATETIME` no meu SQL Server?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 9):

Colunas em tabelas são dados. Dados não possuem formatos. Internamente é até possível algum dado específico ter algum formato mas isto só ocorre com texto e mesmo assim é algo que importa para o dado em si e não para a coluna.

Em uma coluna do tipo `DateTime` existe uma data. Ponto.

Se você quer em algum formato, você deverá pegar a data e criar um texto formatado como deseja. Mas um texto formatado é diferente de uma data. O software não se preocupa com formatos, isto é usado para mostrar para humanos. E o que é mostrado para humanos sempre é um texto, mesmo que este texto represente uma data. Mas é só isto, uma representação.

Uma forma de pegar uma saída formatada seria assim:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 2) AS [YY.MM.DD]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/FormatDate.sql).

Documentação do [`CONVERT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 5):

Como já dito, a data no banco de dados não tem formato.

Então o que você quer saber é **qual formato de data o banco de dados aceita para entrada ou consulta de dados**.

Isso no Microsoft SQL Server depende de alguns fatores:

- Qual o idioma de instalação do banco de dados.
- Qual o idioma do usuário de banco de dados que você está usando para conectar-se.
- Qual formato de data foi especificado (se foi especificado) na sessão com o comando *SET DATEFORMAT*

Se você instala o servidor em um Windows em português, o idioma padrão do banco de dados também ficará em português. Logo, todos os novos usuários terão por padrão o idioma português e então o formato de data aceito pelo banco será **dd/MM/yyyy** e a query abaixo surtirá o efeito desejado:

```
select * from tabela where data = '15/04/2015'
```

O problema é que quando o seu software chegar num cliente que instalou o SQL Server em um Windows em inglês, esta query vai falhar pois o formato de data aceito pelo banco será o americano, **MM/dd/yyyy**.

Tanto quanto pior, se na query você escrevesse `12/04/2015`, em vez de obter um errro você obteria dados inválidos, o que é muito mais perigoso.

## Resolvendo o problema

Felizmente o MS SQL Server aceita um outro formato de data (padrão ISO) que independe de qualquer configuração, que são estes:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]

YYYYMMDD[ hh:mm:ss[.mmm]]
```

Estes formatos independem inclusive do comando *SET DATEFORMAT*.

Então, para a query acima funcionar sempre, você pode escrevê-la assim:

```
select * from tabela where data = '20150415'
```

## Uma forma melhor de resolver o problema

Se você programa uma camada de aplicativo, por exemplo C# ou Java ou PHP... É melhor passar a data para o banco como parâmetro da query em vez de concatenar a data como string.

Fazendo isso, além de não ter que se preocupar com formato de data você ainda pode se beneficiar de uma melhor performance quando a query for reexecutada com datas diferentes.

Leia mais sobre os formatos de data do Microsoft SQL Server: [Datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

Comment: Discordo da afirmação "a data no banco de dados não tem formato", pode ser, por exemplo, a parte inteira represntar a quantidade de dias decorridos a partir de uma data fixada aleatoriamente (dia juliano) e a parte decimal a fração do dia. A data armazenada possui um formato mas pode ser exibida no formato desejado e especificado pelo usuário e para isso o SGBD faz a devida conversão.

Answer (score 3):

O formato de data que o SQLServer usa por defeito depende da linguagem configurada.

Você pode saber qual é esse formato usando o seguinte comando:

```
select dateformat from syslanguages where name = @@LANGUAGE
```

O formato usado durante uma *session* pode ser alterado usando [SET LANGUAGE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx) ou [SET DATEFORMAT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx):

```
SET LANGUAGE { [ N ] 'language' | @language_var } 
SET DATEFORMAT { format | @format_var }
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o comando abaixo:

```
dbcc useroptions;
```

O campo 'DATEFORMAT' mostra o formato padrão.