# O SQL está importando datas em formato diferentes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Estou com problemas quando seleciono uma coluna de data no SQL Server. Acontece que meus dados estão no formato `dd/mm/aaaa` e quando seleciono essa coluna o SQL inverte ficando `aaaa-dd-mm` e na verdade teria que ser `aaaa-mm-dd`.

Isso acontece em alguma datas como `02/12/2014` ele converte como `2014-02-12`.
O tipo de coluna é `datetime2(7)`

Comment: Esse é o formato padrão do banco, creio que não tem como você alterar isso e nem deveria. Essa formatação deve ser feita na aplicação.Use as classes referente a datas que existem em muitas linguagens para isso, assim você não precisa ficar convertendo na mão.

Comment: Qual versão do SQL Server e qual é o tipo da coluna?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 e o tipo de coluna é datetime2(7)

Comment: Kleber, quando for responder alguém nos comentários, lembre-se de citar a pessoa a quem você está respondendo, senão ela não é notificada da sua resposta. Acredito que você respondeu ao questionamento do @rray

Comment: olhe esse exemplo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58521/como-saber-qual-formato-de-datetime-utilizado-em-determinada-coluna-do-sql-serve/58546#58546

Answer (score 3):

Quando efectuares o SELECT usa a seguinte sintaxe:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121)
```

Substituir  função `getdate()` pelo nome da coluna que pretendes converter.

Comment: Isso é valido para o tipo datetime2(7)? ou para DateTime?

Comment: @Marconcilio Souza pode utilizar com ambos o resultado será o mesmo, podes testar desta forma: 
`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), SYSDATETIME(), 121)` sysdatetime devolve um datetime2