# Formatação de data em c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, .net, asp.net-web-api

estou fazendo uma api crud onde tem como propriedades na pasta entities:

```
{
    public class Alunos
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set;}
        public string NomePai { get; set; }
        public string NomeMae { get; set; }
        public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mas no Swagger ao tentar fazer um Post so aceita a data no formato americano e no sql server  tambem e ainda com horario no sql, aqui está o metodo Post:

```
 [HttpPost("Adicionar")]
    public IActionResult Create(string nome, DateTime dataNascimento, string nomePai, string nomeMae, bool ativo)
    {
        var aluno = new Alunos
        {
            Nome = nome,
            DataNascimento = dataNascimento,
            NomePai = nomePai,
            NomeMae = nomeMae,
            Ativo = ativo
        };

        _aluno.Add(aluno);
        _aluno.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu diria que na sua situação voce teria que tratar a data quando voce recebe ela no padrão BR, para o padrão americano antes de gravar no seu banco de dados, agora se voce quer saber o porque isso acontece eu diria:

Se você instala o servidor em um Windows em português, o idioma padrão do banco de dados também ficará em português. Logo, todos os novos usuários terão por padrão o idioma português e então o formato de data aceito pelo banco será dd/MM/yyyy.

então provavelmente foi instalado em uma maquina com o windows em  ingles.

Exemplo: no seu metodo quando voce receber a data no padrão Br faça essa conversão para o padrão En e use essa data para enviar para o banco de dados

```
  var DataEN = ((DateTime)DataBR).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

se quiser saber mais detalhes sobre esse assunto da uma olhada [Como saber qual formato de DATETIME utilizado em determinada coluna do SQL Server?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58521/como-saber-qual-formato-de-datetime-utilizado-em-determinada-coluna-do-sql-serve)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).